# The difference between the unitary matrix in ProjectQ and Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, projectq

Why are not the same unitary matrices in ProjectQ and Qiskit in the following codes:

#### ProjectQ:

```
drawing_engine = CircuitDrawerMatplotlib()

eng = MainEngine(backend = UnitarySimulator(), engine_list = [drawing_engine]+get_engine_list())
qreg = eng.allocate_qureg(3)

theta1 = pi/4

theta2 = pi/5

X | qreg[2]  

with Control(eng, [qreg[2],qreg[1]]):

    Ry(2*theta2) | qreg[0]  

X | qreg[1] 

with Control(eng, [qreg[2],qreg[1]]):

    Ry(2*theta1) | qreg[0]      

X | qreg[2]  

with Control(eng, [qreg[2],qreg[1]]):

    Ry(2*theta2) | qreg[0]  

X | qreg[1] 

with Control(eng, [qreg[2],qreg[1]]):

    Ry(2*theta1) | qreg[0]    

X | qreg[2]  

with Control(eng, [qreg[2],qreg[1]]):

    Ry(2*theta2) | qreg[0]  

X | qreg[1] 

with Control(eng, [qreg[2],qreg[1]]):

    Ry(2*theta1) | qreg[0]  

eng.flush()

print(eng.backend.unitary.real)
```

#### Qiskit:

```
qreg = QuantumRegister(3) 

creg = ClassicalRegister(3) 

circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg,creg)

theta1 = pi/4

theta2 = pi/5

circuit.x(qreg[2])    

circuit.mcry(2*theta2,[ qreg[2], qreg[1] ],qreg[0],None) 
 
circuit.x(qreg[1])

circuit.mcry(2*theta1,[ qreg[2], qreg[1] ],qreg[0],None) 

circuit.x(qreg[2])    

circuit.mcry(2*theta2,[ qreg[2], qreg[1] ],qreg[0],None) 
 
circuit.x(qreg[1])

circuit.mcry(2*theta1,[ qreg[2], qreg[1] ],qreg[0],None) 

circuit.x(qreg[2])    

circuit.mcry(2*theta2,[ qreg[2], qreg[1] ],qreg[0],None)  

circuit.x(qreg[1])

circuit.mcry(2*theta1,[ qreg[2], qreg[1] ],qreg[0],None) 

job = execute(circuit,Aer.get_backend('unitary_simulator'),optimization_level=0)
unitary_matrix=job.result().get_unitary(circuit,decimals=8)

unitary_matrix.real
```

Comment: Without looking at the code: have you tried calling `reverse_bits()` on your qiskit circuit?

Comment: Yeah qiskit uses little endian notation so the statevector is reversed |q_3, q_2, q_1, q_0> for example, which is not most popular convention in my opinion.

Comment: I tried  to call reverse_bits() but I didn't get a unitary matrix like in ProjectQ.